# while não está sendo executado desde o inicio

Tags: c, variáveis, tipagem, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){

 int parar=1; // Condição para parar.
 int a=0, b=0, c=0; //Elevadores
 int count=0; //Numero de pessoas
 char elevador=""; //Elevador

do{

  printf("Elevador: ");
  scanf("%c", &elevador);

  if(elevador == 'a'){
    a++;
    count++;
  }else if(elevador == 'b'){
    b++;
    count++;
  }else if(elevador == 'c'){
     c++;
     count++;
  }else{
     printf("inválido!");
  }

    printf("\nContinuar respondendo? s=1 n=0");
    scanf("%d", &parar);

  }while(parar != 0);
}
```

Estou criado um mini formulário para pesquisa porém ele não está sendo executado da maneira correta, vejam como é retornado para mim:

[image: SS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema básico do código é que está inicializando um caractere como se fosse um *string*, aí é código não lida corretamente com a informação. Use aspas simples para `char`.

Este código pode ser melhorado, mas nem vale fazer já porque ele nem está completo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int parar = 1; // Condição para parar.
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0; //Elevadores
    int count = 0; //Numero de pessoas
    char elevador=' '; //Elevador
    do {
        printf("Elevador: ");
        scanf("%c", &elevador);
        if (elevador == 'a') {
            a++;
            count++;
        } else if (elevador == 'b') {
            b++;
            count++;
        } else if (elevador == 'c') {
           c++;
           count++;
        } else {
            printf("inválido!");
        }
        printf("\nContinuar respondendo? s=1 n=0");
        scanf("%d", &parar);
    } while (parar != 0);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/KPJinK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/unlwpzep-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/CharLiteral.c).

Comment: É necessário sempre iniciar uma variável char?

Comment: Se quiser fazer funcionar sempre corretamente sim, mas pode ter caso que não precisa como otimização, aí tem que se aprofundar.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite.
No código que vc postou tem uma chave que não está abrindo

//essa aqui embaixo onde deixei em negrito

**}** while(parar != 0);
}

Comment: Mano, não entendi o que quis dizer

Comment: onde vc está abrindo essa chave ( } ) que está em frente ao comando WHILE ???
pois se vc reparar tem outra cheve logo depois do comando tbm, provavelmente uma delas está fechando o comando DO e a outra está "perdida"

Comment: Uma é pra fechar o do{} outra pra fechar o main(){}

Comment: @WSS na verdade i problema não é este. Também não entendi a resposta.

Comment: tentou usar o código: 
'system ("pause");
     return(0);'

Comment: Coloque esse código depois do **do**  e faça um teste.